# Google books public api - 401

Tags: javascript, angular

When locally trying to use Google books api to get public data:

Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22)

```
API_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes";
this.http
    .get<GoogleBooksApiInterface>(`${this.API_URL}?q=${title}`)
```

Even after adding `&key=api_key`, the response is the same.

Comment: I know Google/Meta, in general, is moving away from API keys and moving to more secure methods. Google around or even check your email to see if google has made changes-- I know they no longer support Jabber for Google Chat (which is totally unrelated, but more of an indication of how they're changing things)

Comment: Some Google endpoints don't accept API keys anymore and require a more secure authentication method. If some backend service is going to be making this call, they typically recommend using [service account authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spent some time to figure it out and found solution (which is not unfortunately mentioned in google documentation):
to make it works in my case I use NodeJS on the backend side and moved there this API request.

Angular => NodeJS => API call => Angular